# What does the highlighted expression mean

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[What does the highlighted expression mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDE2f.png)

Looks like *E* is a function with arguement *M*. Let *M* be *00*. Hence, *E(00)* equals to plaintext letter A. But how can the following expression can be true: *A ≡ 3 (modulo 26)* ? Can you please explain that?

Comment: $E$ maps $0\to 3,\,$ i.e. $A\to D$. As they say, encryption $E$ cyclically (right) rotates the alphabet by $3$ places $(A\mapsto D,\, B\mapsto E,\ldots)\,$ so its inverse decryption $D$ cyclically (left) rotates by $3,\,$ Note that each letter is encoded by its index in the alphabet, and the cryption functions work with the indices.

Comment: @BillDubuque and I still cannot understand, sorry. Function $E(00)$ returns plaintext letter *A*. But the right side of highlighted expression is a number. How can the letter and a number be compared?

Comment: No, as I said the encryption and decription functions work with integers mod $26$ which are the codes representing the letters (here their index in the alphabet). Here $E(0) = 3$